# Can I stop the matchmaking handler from being called if I cancel the matchmaking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

When you use `GKMatchMaker`'s `findMatchForRequest`, you pass a completion handler to it.

If you call

```
[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker]cancel];
```

The matchmaking will indeed be cancelled. The completion handler you provided will be called. It will be called with an `NSError`, describing that the user cancelled the matchmaking.

Is there a way to also cancel the handler from being called? That is, if I use `cancel`, I would like the handler to never be called, because I already know that the match was cancelled.

Of course, I could have some `wasCancelled` flag - when the handler is called, I can check this flag: if it is true, then do absolutely nothing. Howevever I was wondering if there was a simpler way (namely: cancel the handler from being called).

iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

While the behavior you are seeing is normal and expected if you really don't want the handler to be called for some reason you can nil out the handler before canceling which will prevent it from being called in the event of the cancel. Make sure to reassign the handler before you initiate the next call.

Comment: How do I null it out?